Get items from list2 which is not in list 1

I have 3 columns, Column A and B are the data and Column C is the result.
Try to get the items from Column B which is not available in Column A.
I use this formula in C1 :
=filter(B1:B,countif(B1:B,A1:A)=0)

But got wrong result. For example , I should not get 'd' or 'h' or 'k'
What is the correct formula ?

Swap B1:B with A1:A inside COUNTIF.
=FILTER(B1:B,COUNTIF(A1:A,B1:B)=0)

